# How do I access, from a Parallels VM, an HTTP server running on the Mac host on port 8000?

Tags: network, mojave, virtualization, parallels-desktop

I have a Parallels VM which I'm using to test Internet Explorer and Edge. It's set to use a "shared network", and I can ping the host Mac (via `ping 10.211.55.2`). I've set up my `hosts` file as follows:

```
10.211.55.2 localmac
```

To test, I'm running `python3 -m http.server` on the host, which creates a web server bound to `0.0.0.0:8000`. However, when I try to access this server from the Windows guest, by navigating to `http://localmac:8000`, I get a connection timed out error from Edge.

To reiterate, I *am* able to ping the host machine from the guest, and I can access the Internet from the guest. It's just HTTP from guest to host which seems to fail.

Is there a firewall setting or something which I have to configure to allow incoming connections? It seems like I'm doing everything correctly, according to the other StackExchange answers regarding accessing the host from a Parallels guest, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

The host is MacOS Mojave (MacOS Version 10.14.4). I'm running Parallels Desktop 14, and the guest is a Windows 10 Enterprise Evaluation image (sourced from [Microsoft's VM resources](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/)).

Comment: How do you have the network adapter configured for the guest?  Host, bridged, NAT, etc?

Comment: It's set to "shared network" in Parallels, which I'm guessing means NAT. I can see a new network adapter on the host, with the IP `10.211.55.2`. The guest's network adapter has the IP `10.211.55.3`. I can ping `10.211.55.2` from the guest, but I can't seem to make a HTTP connection.

Comment: Did you manually assign that IP to the host?  Those IP conventions are what Parallels users for its network. You have to remember that shared networking creates a separate network and Parallels acts as a router.

Comment: I did not assign the IPs manually. I'm using Parallel's DHCP to assign IPs.

Comment: Is the macOS firewall on? In that case, have you tried either disabling the firewall (System Preferences>Security & Privacy>Firewall) or adding port 8000 to the firewall (in System Preferences>Security & Privacy>Firewall, press the plus button and then select python3 - you may need to press Shift-Command-G to select the folder)?